# How do you render a border between each Ruby on Rails template collection item but not at the end?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a collection that I rendering but would like to show a border between items and not at the end.  Is this possible?

```
render :partial => 'classrooms/classroom_result', :collection => @result, :as => :classroom
```

_classroom_result.html:

```
<div style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;'>
  <%= classroom.name %>
</div>
```

Basically is there a way to differentiate the last item in the collection for styling purposes?  In this example I don't want to there to be css of border-bottom on the last item because I have a border surrounding the entire collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off this is a CSS issue, not really a Rails issue.

To do this, you need a proper stylesheet. I do not think you can do this with an inline style as you are. Next your `<div>` needs a CSS class to identify this list of `<div>`s and then you use the `:last-child` pseudo-selector to disable the border on the last element.

In your stylesheet:

```
.classroom {
  border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.classroom:last-child {
  border-bottom:0;
}
```

In your partial:

```
<div class="classroom">
  <%= classroom.name %>
</div>
```

That should do it. Also, :last-child will not work in <= IE8, but will in most other relatively recent browsers.

Comment: I never knew you can do this.  Is this crossbrowser compatible?  Does it work in IE?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think it works in IE 8 or before. If you want it to work with IE8 you can try a hack with jQuery or something to add a class with the `border-bottom: 0;` style to the last div. Like $('.classroom:last-child').addClass(...);